How to set the alignment and font in a custom textbox on edit mode
The custom textbox displays the text as expected when not on edit mode, how to show the text vertically centered, with same font and not overlapped in edit mode?
The textbox must allow set the height without affecting the font size or vice versa

My code for the custom textbox:
public partial class TextboxCommon : TextBox
{
    public TextboxCommon() : base()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        AutoSize = false;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        Font = new Font("Calibri light", 16, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        Pen penBorder = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
        Rectangle rectBorder = new Rectangle(e.ClipRectangle.X, e.ClipRectangle.Y, e.ClipRectangle.Width - 1, e.ClipRectangle.Height - 1);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(penBorder, rectBorder);

        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Purple);
        StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat
        {
            LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
        };

        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, this.Font, brush, rectBorder, stringFormat);
    }
}


What edit mode and what are you trying to achieve here besides overriding the height? Drawing border? Just set the Font and ForeColor properties and get rid of the paint part.

Note that the TextBox is not a regular .Net control but a legacy control with a thin layer around it. It will not work well when you subclass it to change its visuals.

Since changing the drawing functions for Windows form components is a bit complicated and requires careful attention to many undocumented issues, and on the other hand, there is no guarantee that it will work exactly right in future versions of Windows, I suggest a simpler method:
Create a UserControl that does not inherit from TextBox and override its OnPaint method as follows. Then drag and drop a TextBox inside this UserControl. It is not necessary to match the dimensions of the TextBox with the dimensions of the UserControl. Because the code applies the size settings.
As we know, before copying the codes in the project, you must double click on the empty space of UserControl to create the OnLoad method.
If you want our controller to be more professional, you can define the BorderColor and BorderThickness constants as published properties in UserControl. Of course, we can publish the required properties and events of the TextBox in the new UserControl.
public partial class TextboxCommon : UserControl
{
    public static readonly Color BorderColor = Color.Red;
    public const int BorderThickness = 1;
    public TextboxCommon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Pen penBorder = new Pen(BorderColor, BorderThickness);
        Rectangle rectBorder = new Rectangle(e.ClipRectangle.X, e.ClipRectangle.Y, e.ClipRectangle.Width - 1, e.ClipRectangle.Height - 1);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(penBorder, rectBorder);
    }
    private void TextboxCommon_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AutoSize = false;
        textBox1.SetBounds(ClientRectangle.X + BorderThickness, ClientRectangle.Y + BorderThickness, ClientRectangle.Width - 2 * BorderThickness, ClientRectangle.Height - 2 * BorderThickness);
        textBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        textBox1.Font = new Font("Calibri light", 16, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Purple;
    }
}

